# How to check element is first child of a parent when mapping with child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am mapping all `textarea` in specific container. I need to check every textarea is first element of parent(`$('.services')`). If not, then add a class to it.

There are several `.services` classes in page and added later after page loaded. Need to only show first textarea child for every `.services` classes. Each `.services` class have many textarea.

```
$('textarea').map(function (i) {
      /* if not first textarea of parent element $('.services') */
      $(this).addClass('hide');
});
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.services > textarea').filter(function() {
    return $(this).index() !== 0;
}).addClass('hide');
```

Comment: I'd probably go with `.services > textarea`

Comment: Thank you. It works great. Out of curosity, I am aking this, how we can solve when there are other elements present before textarea in parent element? Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acmqQ/4/).

Comment: @JustinJohn You are welcome. One option is using `.prevAll()` method. http://jsfiddle.net/aD9M8/

Answer (score 2):

Try with `.each()` like

```
$('.services textarea').each(function(){
    var indx = $(this).index(); 
    if(indx != 0) {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/acmqQ/)

Comment: `gt()` filters the elements according to their indexes in the jQuery collection(_selected elements_) not their parent/chlid relations.

Comment: WHat is the reason to down it..??Tell me first

Comment: I downvoted. As I have already written `:gt()` doesn't work here. It just excludes the first selected element from the _set_.

Comment: Have you seen my first ans and also I have given fiddle for `gt`..??

Comment: `.index()` will also do the same thing

Comment: Yes, I have seen your fiddle, and No `index()` method without argument returns the index of the element in relation to it's siblings.

Comment: :gt() will selects the textareas whose indexes are greaterthan `0`.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work in OP's case, OP wants to exclude the first textarea child of several parent elements.

Comment: Ok I will remove the second..Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `gt()` don't work in my use case.Please check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acmqQ/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".services").find("textarea:eq(0)");
```

reference [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and  [eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not hide all `.services` and then just show the first child?

```
$('.services').hide();
$('.services:first-child').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it,

```
$('.services').each(function(){
   $(this).children('textarea').addClass('hide');
   $(this).children('textarea:first').removeClass('hide').show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.services').each(function(){
  if($(this).not(':first-child')){
    $(this).addClass('hide');
  }
}
```

or:

```
$('.services textarea:not(:first-child)').addClass('hide');
```

or:

```
$('.services').children().not(':first').addClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.services textarea').each(function(){
    var textarea = $(this);
    if(!textarea.is(':first')) {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
    }
});
```